# MSUnity - Registering Types - Generic Abstract Class

Tags: unity-container

I've just implemented the Translator pattern discussed [here](http://richhewlett.com/2010/06/11/a-useful-entity-translator-pattern-object-mapper-template/) and [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff647300.aspx) like so...

ITranslator interface...

```
public interface ITranslator
{
    bool CanTranslate(Type targetType, Type sourceType);
    bool CanTranslate<TTarget, TSource>();
    object Translate(Type targetType, object source);
    TTarget Translate<TTarget>(object source);
}
```

Translator.cs...

```
public abstract class Translator<TBusinessEntity, TServiceEntity> : ITranslator where TBusinessEntity : class
                                                                                where TServiceEntity : class
{
    public bool CanTranslate(Type targetType, Type sourceType)
    {
        return (targetType == typeof(TBusinessEntity) && sourceType == typeof(TServiceEntity)) ||
               (targetType == typeof(TServiceEntity) && sourceType == typeof(TBusinessEntity)); 
    }

    public bool CanTranslate<TTarget, TSource>()
    {
        return CanTranslate(typeof (TTarget), typeof (TSource));
    }

    public TTarget Translate<TTarget>(object source)
    {
        return (TTarget)Translate(typeof(TTarget), source);
    }

    public object Translate(Type targetType, object source)
    {
        if (targetType == typeof(TBusinessEntity))
            return ServiceToBusiness((TServiceEntity)source);

        if (targetType == typeof(TServiceEntity))
            return BusinessToService((TBusinessEntity)source);
        throw new System.ArgumentException("Invalid type passed to Translator", "targetType");  
    }

    protected abstract TServiceEntity BusinessToService(TBusinessEntity value);
    protected abstract TBusinessEntity ServiceToBusiness(TServiceEntity value);
    protected abstract List<TServiceEntity> BusinessToService(List<TBusinessEntity> valueList);
    protected abstract List<TBusinessEntity> ServiceToBusiness(List<TServiceEntity> valueList);
}
```

Here is my StudentFeeTranslator class that implements the Translator abstract methods...

```
public class StudentFeeTranslator : Translator<StudentFee, StudentFeeType>
{
    #region Overrides of Translator<StudentFee,StudentFeeType>

    protected override StudentFeeType BusinessToService(StudentFee value)
    {
        return new
            StudentFeeType
                   {
                        StudentFeeId = value.StudentFeeRefId,
                        FeeId = value.FeeRefId,
                        StudentId = value.StudentRefId,
                        SchoolId = value.SchoolRefId,
                        FeeDate = value.AssessmentDate,
                        FeeAmount = value.AssessmentAmount,
                        Balance = value.UnpaidBalance,
                        FeeTypeId = value.FeeType,
                        Description = value.FeeDescription
                    };
    }

    protected override StudentFee ServiceToBusiness(StudentFeeType value)
    {
        return new
            StudentFee
                   {
                        StudentFeeRefId = value.StudentFeeId,
                        FeeRefId = value.FeeId,
                        StudentRefId = value.StudentId,
                        SchoolRefId = value.SchoolId,
                        AssessmentDate = value.FeeDate,
                        AssessmentAmount = value.FeeAmount,
                        UnpaidBalance = value.Balance,
                        FeeType = (Byte)value.FeeTypeId,
                        FeeDescription = value.Description
                    };
    }

    protected override List<StudentFeeType> BusinessToService(List<StudentFee> valueList)
    {
        return valueList.Select(BusinessToService).ToList();
    }

    protected override List<StudentFee> ServiceToBusiness(List<StudentFeeType> valueList)
    {
        return valueList.Select(ServiceToBusiness).ToList();
    }

    #endregion
}
```

Next is my StudentFeeService class minus the irrelevant methods.  Notice the Translator property tagged for injection...

```
public partial class StudentFeeService : IStudentFeeService
{
    #region Public Members

    [Dependency]
    public ITranslator Translator { get; set; }

    #endregion

    #region Private Methods

    private List<StudentFeeType> ConvertStudentFeeListToListOfStudentFeeTypes(List<StudentFee> studentFees)
    {
        return Translator.Translate<List<StudentFeeType>>(studentFees);
    }

    #endregion
}
```

Finally, here is the code snippet of my attempt to register the Translator class with my Unity container...

```
container.RegisterType(typeof (ITranslator), typeof (Translator<,>));
```

This attempt failed.  My question is how can I register a generic abstract class with a Unity container?  FYI I'm using MSUnity 2.0.

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to map a non-generic interface to an open generic type. How should Unity (or any other container) guess if your service needs a `StudenFeeTranslator` or a `RentalFeeTranslator`? Both implement `ITranslator` and that is all the container can see.

You can register all of your concrete implementations of `ITranslator` giving them individual names. This is something all containers support. And then make Unity inject that specific dependency into the `Translator` property of your service. Something like

```
container.RegisterType(typeof(ITranslator), typeof(StudentFeeTranslator), "StudentFee");
container.RegisterType(typeof(ITranslator), typeof(RentalFeeTranslator), "RentalFee");
container.RegisterType(typeof(IStudentFeeService), typeof(StudentFeeService), 
  new InjectionProperty("Translator", new ResolvedParameter<ITranslator>("StudentFee")));
```

That is a lot of repetetive code though.

Unity does not come with registration conventions out-of-the-box. But the [TecX project](http://tecx.codeplex.com) contains an enhanced configuration engine that would allow you to do something like this:

```
ConfigurationBuilder builder = new ConfigurationBuilder();
builder.Scan(
  scanner =>
    {
      scanner.AddAllImplementationsOf(typeof(ITranslator);
      scanner.AssembliesFromApplicationBaseDirectory();
    });
container.AddExtension(builder);
```

This registers all implementations of `ITranslator` with the name of the implementing class (e.g. the name for `StudentFeeTranslator` would be StudentFeeTranslator) in one go.

If you make your interface generic it would be easier to inject into the property. Matching `ITranslator<X, Y>` to an implementation thereof is not really hard to do.